# Send Ajax message setTimeOut m delay between actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i have been trying to add even delay() or setTimeOut to this simple send message, but i think i do not understand quite well how does this works, i have been "wrapping" the functions but everytime i got a lots of syntax erros, if i "fix" them i got nothing but all actions done one after other, even if i set delay(8000) no delay is reflected actually

this is the script for send message

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sendtofriend.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#message').css("display", "none");
        $('#messagein').css("display", "block");
        $('#messagein').html("<div id='messageinin'></div>");
        $('#messageinin').html("<h2><%= t('generales.thankks') %></h2>")
        .append("<p><%= t('generales.msgsent') %>.</p>")

        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#messagein').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
        });

        $('#message').fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#messagein').css("display", "none");
         $('#message').css("display", "block");
        });

      }
     });
    return false;
  });


});
```

i have tried a lot of stuff, something like this for example

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "sendtofriend.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function() {
            $('#message').css("display", "none");
            $('#messagein').css("display", "block");
            $('#messagein').html("<div id='messageinin'></div>");
            $('#messageinin').html("<h2><%= t('generales.thankks') %></h2>")
            .append("<p><%= t('generales.msgsent') %>.</p>")
            .delay(8000)
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
              $('#messagein').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
            });

            $('#message').fadeIn(1500, function() {
              $('#messagein').css("display", "none");
             $('#message').css("display", "block");
            });

          }
         });
        return false;
      });


    });
```

My goal is `#message` to dissapear when confirmation div '#messagein' is visble, and then dissapear the confirmation and reapper the form to submit another message.

this is the HTML

```
<div id='messagein'></div>
<div id='message'>

<form action="" method="post" id="sendfriendd">


<div id="inpumail" >

   <!-- <input type="text" name="" id="youremailaddress" size="40" value="<%= t('generales.tucorreoo') %>" class="text-input"  />  -->

     <input type="text" name="youremailaddress" id="youremailaddress" size="40" value="<%= t('generales.tucorreoo') %>" class="text-input" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='#ccc'; this.value='<%= t('generales.tucorreoo') %>'}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<%= t('generales.tucorreoo') %>') {this.style.color='#000'; this.style.fontStyle='normal'; this.value=''}" style="color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-style: normal;"/>  
    <label class="error" for="youremailaddress" id="youremailaddress_error">This field is required.</label>  

</div>


<br>
<div id="inpumail2" >


    <input type="text" name="friendsemailaddress" id="friendsemailaddress" size="40" value="<%= t('generales.amigcorreoo') %>" class="text-input" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='#ccc'; this.value='<%= t('generales.amigcorreoo') %>'}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<%= t('generales.amigcorreoo') %>') {this.style.color='#000'; this.style.fontStyle='normal'; this.value=''}" style="color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-style: normal;"/>  
    <label class="error" for="friendsemailaddress" id="friendsemailaddress_error">This field is required.</label>

</div>


<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value=" <%= t('generales.enviarcorreoo') %> " class="enterrenvi">
</form>
```

Comment: i still do not understand what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `delay` doesn't work in this example (after append) since it only affects jquery animations. setTimeout should do the job when used properly.

try removing the delay and changing:

```
$('#message').fadeIn(1500, function() {
    $('#messagein').css("display", "none");
    $('#message').css("display", "block");
});
```

into:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#messagein').fadeOut(1000); //animate display none
},5000); //timeout 5 secs
```